# ffmpeg-python wrapper ffmpeg.run() getting FILENOTFOUNDERROR

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure out and learn how to use the ffmpeg-python wrapper and am getting a file not found error. both the mp4 file I'm trying to process and the python file are both in a folder on my desktop. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly here.

I'm running windows 10 32bit, python 3.6 and have ffmpeg-python 0.16.0 installed. Is there additional packages I need installed in order for this to work? I tried the same code on my 64 bit windows 10 desktop and got the same error.

```
import ffmpeg

videoInput = ffmpeg.input('vid.mp4')

videoOutput = videoInput.output('test.avi')

videoOutput.run()
```

This is the error that I get in python shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\geral\Desktop\PythonPrograms\ffmpegexample.py", line 7, in <module>
    videoOutput.run()
  File "C:\Users\geral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 300, in run
    overwrite_output=overwrite_output,
  File "C:\Users\geral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 272, in run_async
    args, stdin=stdin_stream, stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream)
  File "C:\Users\geral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\geral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well I figured it out and it was actually really quite simple. Hopefully this will help anyone who is new to ffmpeg or ffmpeg-python.

After reading through the traceback: Probably 100 times. I realised that ffmpeg probably wasn't packaged with ffmpeg-python and I never installed ffmpeg myself. So I simply installed ffmpeg using [This Installation Guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows) and everything worked.

I Probably have this memorised by now, Ive read it enough times.
[ffmpeg-python API Reference](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/)

So Long story short you must have ffmpeg installed before ffmpeg-python will work.

Comment: An addition to the first-floor answer. After installing FFmpeg and setting environment variables, it's a good idea to reboot because the Windows environment path is not updated when you are currently in the python environment/editor.

Comment: I used pip to install ffmpeg, but still getting the FileNotFoundError - running on a mac, mind you.